# $\lfloor x\rfloor + \lfloor y\rfloor \leq \lfloor x+y\rfloor$ for every pair of numbers of $x$ and $y$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Give a convincing argument that $\lfloor x\rfloor + \lfloor y\rfloor \leq \lfloor x+y\rfloor$ for every pair of numbers $x$ and $y$. Could someone please explain how to prove this? I attempted to say that the largest values that could be added to $x$ and $y$ is $0.99$ and that doing so still made $\lfloor x\rfloor + \lfloor y\rfloor < \lfloor x+y\rfloor$. However, my answer was not accepted.

Comment: One reason your answer was not accepted because one could add 0.999, and that is larger than 0.99.

Comment: Yeah, but he was leaning more towards an actual proof. He didn't provide us with an actual proof, however. I just want to make sure I don't miss this question if it appears on our midterm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \epsilon_1$ and $y = \lfloor y \rfloor + \epsilon_2$.

Then $\lfloor x + y \rfloor = \lfloor\lfloor x \rfloor + \epsilon_1 + \lfloor y \rfloor + \epsilon_2\rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor + \lfloor \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 \rfloor \ge \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor$.

Comment: A simpler version:$$
\newcommand{\Xo}[1]{\\#1\quad&\quad\unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\Xt}[1]{\mbox{#1}\\\quad&\quad\phantom{\unicode{x201c}}}
\newcommand{\Xs}[1]{\mbox{#1}\unicode{x201d}\\\quad&}
\newcommand{\Xf}[1]{\lfloor#1\rfloor}
\begin{align}\quad&
    \Xf{x+y}
\Xo\ge\Xt{using $\;z \ge \Xf{z}\;$, twice; both $\;+\;$ and $\;\Xf{\cdot}\;$ are}\Xt{monotonic w.r.t. $\;\ge\;$ -- this seems the simplest}\Xs{way to introduce $\;\Xf{x}\;$ and $\;\Xf{y}\;$}
    \Xf{\Xf{x}+\Xf{y}}
\Xo=\Xt{$\;\Xf{x}\;$ and $\;\Xf{y}\;$ and so their sum are}\Xs{all integers}
    \Xf{x}+\Xf{y}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor = n$ then $x = n + r$ where $0 \leq r < 1$ and If $\left \lfloor y \right \rfloor = n'$ then $y = n' + r'$ where $0 \leq r' < 1$. Then $$x+y = n+n'+r+r'\geq n + n' = \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor $$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = a + m$ and $y = b + n$ where $a, b$ are integers and $m,n$ are real numbers such that $0 \le m,n < 1$. Then,

$$\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor = a + b$$

while

$$\begin{align}\lfloor x + y \rfloor &= \lfloor a + b + m + n \rfloor\\
&= a + b + \lfloor m + n \rfloor\\
& \ge a + b\\
&= \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor\end{align}$$

Equality occurs when the fractional part of $x$ and $y$ sum up to be less than $1$, in which case $\lfloor m + n \rfloor = 0$. For example, $x = 0.5$ and $y = 1.1$.

Answer (score 0):

There are additional answers at the following duplicate(s):

[How to prove that $\lfloor a\rfloor+\lfloor b\rfloor\leq \lfloor a+b\rfloor$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217644/how-to-prove-that-lfloor-a-rfloor-lfloor-b-rfloor-leq-lfloor-ab-rfloor)

(I'm making this community wiki so that anyone can add to it in case other instances come to light.)